# Расширение .phtml: имеет ли смысл использовать?

Tags: php, html

Интересен стал вопрос: имеет ли смысл использовать расширение .phtml для файлов, которые содержат преимущественно html разметку?

Comment: php чем не устраивает ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, да всем устраивает, просто интересно

Answer (score 3):

.phtml было стандартным расширением файла для программ PHP 2. .php3 занял место для PHP 3. Когда вышел PHP 4, они переключились на прямой .php .